# Java-function that returns dynamic type of object

Tags: java

If I have two subclasses `Employee` and `Intern` that extends both the class `Person`. Suppose I have `List<Person> contacts` that is a list that contains everybody working in the company, `Employee` and `Intern`

Now I want to write a function `findPerson(String name)`. This function supposes to return the person by searching their name in `contacts`, without knowing if they belong to `Employee` or `Intern` in advance. However, I would want to return the object if it is found.

However, I don't think Java can return dynamic type for a function. Is there anything I can do instead of writing two functions?

I have tried to make the function to return object type `Person`. However, in that way I can't cast them to the appropriate type, especially I won't be able to know if they are `Employee` or `Intern`

Comment: Why do you need to cast them?

Comment: Maybe you should use "instance of"?

Comment: @AndrewVershinin Because if I specify Company as return type of the function, then I can't perform employee-specific operations on the returned object.

Comment: First of all, something called `findPerson` shouldn't return something called `Company`.  It sounds like the abstract parent class here should be called `Person`, not `Company`.  Aside from that, `findPerson` should indeed return a `Person`.  Functionality specific to any individual child class which implements `Person` would be encapsulated in that class and you'd just call the relevant abstract method on `Person`.  If these two types are so different that the abstract class doesn't represent them, you're breaking Liskov Substitution.

Comment: Why would Employee or Intern extend Company? Also, what if a Intern or Employee share the same name? What would findPerson(String name) return? You're going to need something like findIntern, findEmployee, or findAny.

Comment: Generally a subclass describes an "is-a" relationship. An Employee is *not* a Company. A Company "has-a" Employee.

Comment: Yes yes, I understand I might not have provided a good example. Just my main point is how to implement such a function (Suppose that I have the right hierarchy). I just want to test something simple before implement to my real project. I didn't want to complicate the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method Contacts.findPerson can have a generic return type, like:

```
    <T extends Person > T findPerson(String name)
```

This will give the caller the specific kind of Person (I think you meant Person, not Company, right?) that they are looking for. To ensure that the returned type T matches a particular class you can say:

```
    <T extends Person > T findPerson(Class<T> type, name)
```

Now the type T will be bound to the same type as the class passed in, so usage looks like:

```
    var intern = contacts.findPerson(Intern.class, "Elon Musk");
```

Comment: Thanks. Do i have to specify the type to cast in the parameter? Suppose that I want this function to return the first person found with the same name, regardless if he/she is an employee or an intern.

Comment: I tried to use instanceOf to verify and return (Employee)personFound and (Intern)personFound, but IDE warned me that I can't return Employee, it has to be T.

Comment: @YanZhuang If you want the type to be automatically cast you have to supply the class. What's happening is that the class you're passing in becomes the type T. So the return type will be of that class since the return type is T. If you want either to be returned, you can return Person, but you'll have to inspect the type by hand with instanceof if it matters which kind of person was returned.

Comment: @YanZhuang Try casting the person to a T. You may have to ignore a warning, but I think that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need two functions - `findEmployee` and `findIntern`, with respective `instanceof` checks:

```
Optional<Employee> findEmployee(List<Company> list, String name) {
    for (Company c : list) {
        if (c instanceof Employee && c.getName().equals(name)) {
            return Optional.of((Employee) c);
        }
    }

    return Optional.empty();
}
```

But I would think about how to modify the `Company` class, so there wouldn't be a need to cast it to a particular subclass (use polymorphism).

Answer (score 1):

> I have two subclasses Employee and Intern that extends both the class Company

As you [mentioned in a Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230890/java-function-that-returns-dynamic-type-of-object/66233186#comment117093995_66230890), that naming does not make sense. So let's change that to `Person` as the parent class, with two subclasses, `Employee` & `Intern`. We will forget `Company`.

## Sealed classes

When all possible subclasses are known at compile-time, then we should be using the new [sealed classes](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/397) feature being previewed in Java 16.

Our superclass, `Person`.

```java
package work.basil.example.extending;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

public abstract sealed class Person
        permits Employee, Intern
{
    // Member fields
    UUID id;
    String name;
    LocalDate whenHired;

    // Constructors
    public Person ( final UUID id , final String name , final LocalDate whenHired )
    {
        this.id = Objects.requireNonNull( id );
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull( name );
        this.whenHired = Objects.requireNonNull( whenHired );
    }

    // Logic
    Period getPeriodOfEmployment ( )
    {
        ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
        Period p = Period.between( this.whenHired , today );
        return p;
    }

    // Object overrides.

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Person{ " +
                "id=" + id +
                " | name='" + name + '\'' +
                " | whenHired=" + whenHired +
                " }";
    }
}
```

The two concrete subclasses, `Employee` and `Intern`.

```java
package work.basil.example.extending;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.UUID;

public final class Employee extends Person
{
    public Employee ( UUID id , String name , LocalDate whenHired )
    {
        super( id , name , whenHired );
    }
}
```

```java
package work.basil.example.extending;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.UUID;

public final class Intern extends Person
{
    public Intern ( UUID id , String name , LocalDate whenHired )
    {
        super( id , name , whenHired );
    }
}
```

## Find `Person` objects by name

You asked:

> write a function findPerson(String name) … without knowing if they belong to Employee or Intern in advance

Both `Employee` and `Intern` inherit a `name` member field from their superclass `Person`. So we do not care about which sub-type. Just ask for the name and compare to desired name.

Of course, we may find zero, one, or multiple `Person` objects carrying that name. So we should return a `List` or `Set` of the found objects. For `Set`, we would need implementations of `equals` & `hashCode`. We have not yet written those, so let's stick with `List` for now.

```java
    List < Person > fetchPeopleByName ( final String name , final List < Person > people )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( people );
        List < Person > peopleSharingName = new ArrayList <>( people.size() );
        for ( Person person : people )
        {
            if ( person.name.equalsIgnoreCase( name ) )
            {
                peopleSharingName.add( person );
            }
        }
        return List.copyOf( peopleSharingName );  // Return unmodifiable list.
    }
```

Code to exercise that method.

```java
        List < Person > people = List.of(
                new Employee( UUID.fromString( "a4dcf239-305f-40f1-b6cc-32e3e6643451" ) , "Alice" , LocalDate.of( 2008 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ) ,
                new Intern( UUID.fromString( "e5ac2a48-f25a-42e1-af58-6ce597cc93ed" ) , "Bob" , LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.DECEMBER , 7 ) ) ,
                new Intern( UUID.fromString( "2c24630b-b7e2-4e9f-87ab-7c996137894f" ) , "Carol" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 11 ) ) ,
                new Employee( UUID.fromString( "4b1f918d-c95d-44c5-a85d-d092e3b83c51" ) , "Demetri" , LocalDate.of( 2011 , Month.MARCH , 16 ) )
        );

        List < Person > bobs = this.fetchPeopleByName( "Bob" , people );
        System.out.println( "bobs = " + bobs );
```

When run we find a single `Person` object with a name matching "Bob".

```
bobs = [Person{ id=e5ac2a48-f25a-42e1-af58-6ce597cc93ed | name='Bob' | whenHired=2020-12-07 }]
```

You said of your own attempt at this last method:

> I have tried to make the function to return object type <strike>Company</strike> Person.

Yes, we can return `Person` objects because we are search through `Person` objects by a member field declared on the `Person` super-type. So we do not care about the sub-type, `Employee` or `Intern`.

You also said of your attempt at this method:

> However, in that way I can't cast them to the appropriate type, especially I won't be able to know if they are Employee or Intern

No casting needed. When asking for their name, a member field on the superclass `Person`, any objects of either subclass `Employee` or `Intern` will respond by providing their name. So being a `Employee` or `Intern` is irrelevant to getting their name.

## Find `Person` objects by their subtype `Employee`

You may have other situations where you do indeed care about their subtype. For example, say we need to send each employee information about their employment-benefits plan. The interns have no such benefits. So we want to send only to the subset of `Person` objects that happen to be of the `Employee` subclass. Here is some code for that.

Let's make a method to traverse a list of `Person` objects to return only objects of the subclass `Employee`.

We test the concrete class using `instanceOf`. In older Java we must cast after passing the `instanceOf` test: `( Employee ) person`. In the latest Java versions, new syntax makes the casting automatic and implicit.

```java
    List < Employee > fetchEmployees ( final List < Person > people )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( people );
        List < Employee > employees = new ArrayList <>( people.size() );
        for ( Person person : people )
        {
            if ( person instanceof Employee employee )   // New syntax eliminates need to cast explicitly.
            {
                employees.add( employee );
            }
        }
        return List.copyOf( employees );
    }
```

Code to exercise that method.

```java
        List < Person > people = List.of(
                new Employee( UUID.fromString( "a4dcf239-305f-40f1-b6cc-32e3e6643451" ) , "Alice" , LocalDate.of( 2008 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ) ,
                new Intern( UUID.fromString( "e5ac2a48-f25a-42e1-af58-6ce597cc93ed" ) , "Bob" , LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.DECEMBER , 7 ) ) ,
                new Intern( UUID.fromString( "2c24630b-b7e2-4e9f-87ab-7c996137894f" ) , "Carol" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 11 ) ) ,
                new Employee( UUID.fromString( "4b1f918d-c95d-44c5-a85d-d092e3b83c51" ) , "Demetri" , LocalDate.of( 2011 , Month.MARCH , 16 ) )
        );

        List < Employee > emps = this.fetchEmployees( people );
        System.out.println( "emps = " + emps );
```

When run, we find two employees. One named "Alice", the other "Demetri".

```
emps = [Person{ id=a4dcf239-305f-40f1-b6cc-32e3e6643451 | name='Alice' | whenHired=2008-01-23 }, Person{ id=4b1f918d-c95d-44c5-a85d-d092e3b83c51 | name='Demetri' | whenHired=2011-03-16 }]
```

## Combine search for subtype `Employee` *and* by name field

We can combine our two methods to produce a list of `Employee` objects with a certain name.

```java
List < Person > people = List.of(
        new Employee( UUID.fromString( "a4dcf239-305f-40f1-b6cc-32e3e6643451" ) , "Alice" , LocalDate.of( 2008 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ) ,
        new Intern( UUID.fromString( "e5ac2a48-f25a-42e1-af58-6ce597cc93ed" ) , "Bob" , LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.DECEMBER , 7 ) ) ,
        new Intern( UUID.fromString( "2c24630b-b7e2-4e9f-87ab-7c996137894f" ) , "Carol" , LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 11 ) ) ,
        new Employee( UUID.fromString( "4b1f918d-c95d-44c5-a85d-d092e3b83c51" ) , "Demetri" , LocalDate.of( 2011 , Month.MARCH , 16 ) )
);

// Empty list. Our only "Bob" is an intern, not an employee.
List < Employee > employeesNamedBob = this.fetchEmployees( this.fetchPeopleByName( "Bob" , people ) );  

// A list of one `Employee` object named "Demetri". 
List < Employee > employeesNamedDemetri = this.fetchEmployees( this.fetchPeopleByName( "Demetri" , people ) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your so specific explanations!!